# The final character for the string '<img src="data:image\' contains '\'

Tags: salesforce, force.com

The following code gives me an error because the final character for the first string contains '\'

How do I fix this?

```
myLog.EmailHTML__c.replaceAll('<img src="data:image\', '<img src="data:image/');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using single '\' use double '\'

```
myLog.EmailHTML__c.replaceAll('<img src="data:image\\', '<img src="data:image/');
```

Hopefully it will work!!